# Form data is not saved in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a funny issue with a rails app. I upgraded from `rails 3.2` to `rails 4.1`.

For some reason, one particular post 'form' just would not be processed on my VPS, but on my local server it submits.

I simulated my production server. It works well, but I still can't figure out why it won't save on the production server.

My params hash is fine, it is submitted, my csrf token is fine, but it just won't be processed. Has anyone experienced something like this?

This is my create action in my controller

## conservtypes_controller.rb

```
def create

  selected_conservtypes = params[:conservtype][:conservice_id]
 #Rails.logger.debug "Printing the params hash here"  
 #raise  params.inspect
 #Rails.logger.debug "Params hash printed just above here"
 selections =[]
 selected_conservtypes.each{|sc| selections << {:undpuser_id => params[:conservtype][:undpuser_id],:conservice_id => sc,:consultant_id=>params[:conservtype][:consultant_id]} unless sc.empty?}
 selections.delete_if {|scn| Conservtype.count(:conditions => scn) > 0}
  
  if selections.size <= 0
    flash[:error] = 'You have already selected all the submitted services'
     puts params.inspect 
     #verify_user_section
  elsif Conservtype.create(selections)
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully selected Service(s)"
     verify_user_section
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Unable to add your selections '
      verify_user_section
    
  end
  
end
```

Comment: try create! with a bang, to find out the validation errors

Comment: I did try all options and forms of debugging and diagnostics, it does not return any error. funny thing is i can even see the submitted params hash and everything is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by it does not return an error? Which branch of that if does it go in?

Comment: It goes in the first 'if' and returns you've already selected all submitted services' in the flash. The irony is params.inspect does not show anything and I know the params hash isn't empty.

Comment: Basically it's really that rails does not for some weird reason see the params hash otherwise code works. So my awe is in why would the submitted params be empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I finally fixed the issue by downgrading the rails gem from rails 4.1 to rails 4.0 and everything worked fine.